# Nav Drawer selection depends upon current Supported fragment manager visible in the HomeActivity

Tags: android-support-library

Whenever I try to select a particular nav drawer in home activity, it shows only the first item selected.

But I want to select particular item for currently selected fragments. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();       
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
        itemToBeChecked = R.id.nav_home;
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home).setChecked(true);
    } 
}
```